# Proof of if $|a-b| < \frac{\beta}{2}$ and $|b-c| < \frac{\beta}{2}$, then $|a-c| < \beta$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

So I'm reading *Real Analysis* by Jay Cummings and he says that

If $|a-b| < \frac{\beta}{2}$ and $|b-c| < \frac{\beta}{2}$, then $|a-c| < \beta$

because
$|a-c| = |a-b+b-c| \leq |a-b|+ |b-c|= \frac{\beta}{2}+ \frac{\beta}{2}=\beta$

---

But if you follow the above statement, doesn't this imply that $|a-c| \leq \beta$, not $|a-c| < \beta$?

because the triangle inequality gives us the $\leq$ sign, not the $<$ sign. Did Cummings make a mistake here?

Comment: You have $|a-c| \le |a-b|+ |b-c| \color{red}{<} \frac{\beta}{2}+ \frac{\beta}{2}=\beta$, but not $|a-c| < \frac{\beta}{2}$.

Comment: There are several big flaws in what you wrote.  First of all,  I  assume you meant $\beta $ and not $\frac {\beta}2$.   Secondly, it is clearly not true that the assumptions imply $|a-b|+|b-c|=\frac {\beta}2+\frac {\beta}2$.  In fact, that equality is not possible.

Comment: @lulu are you talking to me or Martin R ?

Comment: @EmilyBurkenhamen  You.

Comment: $|a-c|\lt\frac\beta 2$ doesn't hold with the given premises (a concrete counterexample: $a=\frac\beta 2$, $c=0$ and $b=\frac\beta 4$ for some $\beta\gt 0$. Though $|a-c|\lt\beta$ holds as shown in the above comments.

Comment: @lulu going back to your first comment, I agree with what you said. That was my thought as well. I think Cummings has a typo here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the argument is
$$
|a-c| = |a-b+b-c| \leq |a-b|+ |b-c|\color{red}< \frac{\beta}{2}+ \frac{\beta}{2}=\beta
$$
with $\color{red}<$ in place of $=$. If so, then you can conclude that $|a-c|<\beta$. The final statement connecting $|a-c|$ and $\beta$ is governed by the "weakest link" (or is that the strongest link?), which is the strict inequality $\color{red}<$.

The statement $|a-c|<\beta$ does imply that $|a-c|\le \beta$, though, since $x<y$ implies $x\le y$. Given that $x<y$ implies $x\le y$, the above argument can also be written
$$
|a-c| = |a-b+b-c| \leq |a-b|+ |b-c|\color{red}\le \frac{\beta}{2}+ \frac{\beta}{2}=\beta
$$
since every link in the chain is a true statement. From this reasoning you would conclude $|a-c|\le\beta$.

Comment: So Cummings did, in fact, make a typo then since what I wrote was false and that was directly from the textbook

Comment: Another typo: In your subject line and in the first equation, the rightmost $\frac\beta2$ should be $\beta$.

Comment: I am just now realizing that lol. I was focused on the $\leq$ typo that Cummings made and failed to realize my own typo haha